# Java совмещение getter и switch

Tags: java, android-studio

Как создать в Java getter, в котором есть входящие числа и используется switch для выбора исходящего числа?

Сие есть мой неправильный пример:

```
 switch (randomOperatorLogicka) {
            case 1:
                float vysledekLogicka;
                vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka + cislo2Logicka;
                this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
                return vysledekLogicka;
                break;
            case 2:
                vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka - cislo2Logicka;
                this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
                return vysledekLogicka;
                break;
            case 3:
                vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka * cislo2Logicka;
                this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
                return vysledekLogicka;
                break;
            case 4:
                if (cislo1Logicka == 0) {
                    do {
                        cislo2Logicka = random.nextInt(11);
                    } while (cislo2Logicka != 0);
                    vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka / cislo2Logicka;
                    this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
                    return vysledekLogicka;
                    break;
                } else {
                    vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka / cislo2Logicka;
                    this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
                    return vysledekLogicka;
                    break;
                }
        }
        float vysledekLogickap;
        return vysledekLogickap;
    }
```

Comment: В вашем коде ошибка в том что у вас `float vysledekLogicka;` внутри case. Вынесите ее перед switch

Comment: и break после return лишний

Comment: @Виктор согласен )

Answer (score 1):

```
public double calculate (int randomOperatorLogicka, int cislo1Logicka, int cislo2Logicka) {
    double vysledekLogicka = 0;
    switch (randomOperatorLogicka) {
        case 1:
            vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka+cislo2Logicka;
            break;
        case 2:
            vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka-cislo2Logicka;
            break;
        case 3:
            vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka*cislo2Logicka;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (cislo1Logicka == 0) cislo2Logicka = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 12);
            vysledekLogicka = cislo1Logicka/cislo2Logicka;
            break;
    }
    //this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka;
    return vysledekLogicka;
}
```

Comment: У вас очень много дублирующего кода, что делает его нечитаемым. Напишите свой метод примерно так, при этом в качестве аргументов подавайте нужные значения, а принимайте результат. Как вы можете наблюдать строка this.vysledek = vysledekLogicka; закомментирована. Дело в том, что раскомментировать ее можно и это будет работать, но стоит ли так писать код... Это вопрос на самостоятельное изучение.

Comment: еще не стоит писать дополнение к ответу в комментарий :) Нажмите кнопку "править" под ответом и допишите прямо в ответ, что вы хотели добавить по решению проблемы вопросе, а комментарий удалите